# How to wrap classes with display:none tags?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a piece of code set up so that every time the user clicks on certain divs, the displaynone class is added (these divs already have class names for CSS):

```
 $(".header").click(function () {
            $(this).addClass('displaynone');
        });
```

I have a button on the bottom of my page that calls this function

```
function export(){
            var fullhtml = $("#mybody").html();  }
```

How would I call `.wrap()` so that it searches each `div` class name for 'displaynone' and then wraps it in something like

```
<div style="display:none"></div>
```

I'm doing it this way because I need to send a form to dompdf where the user can dynamically click headers to "hide" them on the PDF document but the headers still need to appear on the HTML version (hence I can't just use .css `('display', 'none')`).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.displaynone').wrap('<div style="display:none;"></div>');
```

Comment: You don't need the `each`, just `$('.displaynone').wrap('<div style="display: none;">')` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a string of HTML like this:

```
var html = '<div><div class="displaynone"></div><div>pancakes</div><div class="displaynone"></div></div>';
```

Then you could do this to wrap the `.displaynone` elements and append it to `#pancakes`:

```
var $html = $(html);
$html.find('.displaynone').wrap('<div style="display: none;">');
$('#pancakes').append($html);
```

If your HTML isn't conveniently wrapped in a `<div>` then you can add one and unwrap it with `html`:

```
var html = '<div>' + incoming_html + '</div>';
// as above
$('#pancakes').append($html.html());
```

Or use `unwrap` to unwrap the extra `<div>`:

```
var html = '<div>' + incoming_html + '</div>';
// as above
$('#pancakes').append($html.unwrap());
```

Useful references:

- [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find)
- [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html)
- [`unwrap`](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)
- [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap)